# SessionHandler баг?

Tags: сессия, php

Warning: SessionHandler::close(): Parent session handler is not open in D:\Server\WAMP_Denewer\home\goodwebmaster\www\engine\classes\identification.php on line 114

на 114 строчке: session_destroy();

сам session_destroy работает при этом!

В чем дело?
PHP 5.4
Вот код моего оброботчика сессий:

```
<?php
class session extends SessionHandler {
    public $start = false;
    function __construct() {
        session_name('system1');
        session_set_save_handler($this);
        session_save_path(ROOT_DIR.'sessions/');
        //register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
        //ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
        //ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 120960);
        //echo ini_set('session.save_handler', 'SQLite');
        $this->start=session_start();
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime) {
        global $db;
        $IPs=array();
        if (empty($_SESSION['id'])) return false;
        foreach (glob(session_save_path().'sess_*') as $filename) {
            //Проверяем не пора ли удалить сессию 
            if ((filemtime($filename) + 200 < time()) && (basename($filename)!='sess_'.session_id())) {
                preg_match('/id_ip\|s\:3\:\"([0-9\:]+)\"\;/',file_get_contents($filename),$id_ip);
                if (!empty($id_ip[1])) {
                    $IPs[$id_ip[1]]++;
                } 
                unlink($filename); // Удаляем сессию    
            }
        }

        $cIPs=array_unique($IPs);
        foreach ($cIPs AS $v){
            $db->query('UPDATE `ip` SET `open_sessions`=`open_sessions`-'.$v.' WHERE `id` IN (\''.implode('\',\'',array_keys($IPs,$v)).'\')');
        }
    }

    private function unserializeSession($data) {
                        //$tmp_sess=$this->unserializesession(file_get_contents($filename)); // $tmp_sess у нас теперь аналогична $_SESSION той сессии
        $vars=preg_split('/([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff^|]*)\|/', $data,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        for($i=0; $vars[$i]; $i++) $result[$vars[$i++]]=unserialize($vars[$i]);
        return $result;
    }       
}
```

Comment: вроде что то нашел https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63379

Comment: дайте лайков чтобы в итоге у меня было 50 очков
P.S. система требует минимум 50 очков что бы я смог ответить на свой вопрос

Comment: Лайкнул :)

Answer (score 1):

Данное поведение являться багом, подробнее тут > https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63379
Единственное решение отлавливать ошибку я решил ее таким образом

```
@session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос интересный. Попробуйте в конструктор добавить `parent::__construct();`.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in ...